# UWP: 'CurrentApp' crashes in certification

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows

I have the problem that I don't know whether to use `CurrentApp` or `CurrentAppSimulator` when submitting an UWP App to the Store.

When I changed my code from `CurrentAppSimulator` to `CurrentApp` it did not only crash on my personal computer running the tests, but also in the certification process. How do I fix that? Obviously the app has not been published at that point, but I also cannot use `CurrentAppSimulator`, because the package getting certificated will also be in the Store eventually ...

What am I supposed to do to fix that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely lack of network access (which CurrentApp relies on) rather than a problem with CurrentApp itself.

Handle exceptions from the CurrentApp call so failure doesn't cause an app crash. CurrentApp can fail if it can't reach the store server. This can be if the app isn't published (likely in your local test) or if the network isn't available (likely in the cert test and possible in real world customer use)

See [Avoid Common Certification Failures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/avoid-common-certification-failures)

Comment: When I check for the network access, as expected, the app still fails the windows app certification tests (when my network has access). Is that fine?

Comment: No, the app should succeed WACK locally. You'll need to test with and handle the network being disconnected. A single check may miss other scenarios.

Comment: I know how to check for network access. How would I check if the store server is available for my app (cert and test case)? And in addition, I doubt that I cannot get CurrentApp without network access - the app needs to have license information available, even if the network is disconnected.

Comment: You can't proactively check if the server is available. You'll need to handle the exception if it isn't. The same for networking, since the network connection could be lost between a proactive check and when the app actually uses the network.

Answer (score 0):

Apps submitted to the store must use the `CurrentApp` class.

Looking at the information available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp), one can read the following:

> This object obtains its data from the Windows Store, so you must have a developer account and the app must be published in the Windows Store. **Before** submitting to the Windows Store, you can test your code with a simulated version of this class (whose state is initialized from an XML file). See CurrentAppSimulator.

Comment: You did not answer my question. When I submit the app (with `CurrentApp`), it does not pass certification, because it crashes on startup. I verified that the crash is due to `CurrentApp`.

Comment: I understand you can't test with `CurrentApp` but Microsoft certification team can. What error are they reporting on their side when certifying the app?

Comment: "Unfortunately, we can’t test your app: 

Reason:
The app silently terminates at launch.

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Launch the app.
2. Notice that the app silently terminates at launch."

Comment: With `CurrentAppSimulator` the app runs fine in debug and release mode

Comment: @jonhue When you create your package for submission, you should use `CurrentApp` instead. Do you pass the WACK Test before uploading your package to Dashboard?

Comment: @MattewWu-MSFT Only with `CurrentAppSimulator`, with `CurrentApp` it fails all launch tests.